# What kind of languages do Deep Neural Network models of Microsoft Translate Text API cover?

Tags: azure

I am surveying Microsoft Translate Text API.
I learned that it has two type of translator model, newer Deep Neural Network model, DNN, and traditional Statistical Machine Translation, SMT.

I also found the following instruction,

```
Microsoft Translator supports 60 languages for text translation through the Microsoft Translator API.
```

However, I could not find how may languages the DNN model covers.
Does DNN model cover 60 langues all?
please tell me it.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/languages.aspx

Comment: @G.Y:Thank you for telling me it. In the site, It just list up 60 language but it does not mention about what kind of language the DNN model covers when it translate a text. Thank you again.

Comment: it says - scroll down in the page a bit.. seek for Neural Network (NN) Powered Languages

Comment: @G.Y:thank you for telling me it again. It says "These neural network models are available for all *****speech***** languages through the Microsoft Translator Speech API and through the Translator text API. I suppose it focuses on *****speech*****. So I am not sure it can apply to text translation. Thank you very much again.

Comment: hehe.. you should focus on what you read my friend.. "These neural network models are available for all speech languages through the Microsoft Translator Speech API **-->and through the Translator text API.<--**"

Comment: @G.Y:thank you again. I read the part but I could not have confidence that there are more languages supported by DNN model than listed up in the item of "speech languages ...". That is, some languages supported by DNN for translating speech may not be all supported by DNN for translating text. I really appreciate you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the and is indeed important. Please know more languages will be added soon to the list below: The following neural network models are available for all speech languages through the Microsoft Translator Speech API ***and*** through the Translator text API (plus the Korean text language) by using the ”generalnn” category ID:
Arabic, 
Chinese (Mandarin), 
English, 
French, 
German, 
Italian, 
Japanese, 
Korean, 
Portuguese, 
Russian, 
Spanish, 
The list is updated regularly, and you can find it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/languages.aspx